# How can I structure these callbacks to get me the info I want?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

Maybe I've been staring at my code too long or maybe I'm using too many callbacks elsewhere or something, but I can't figure out the logistics of this one. I know the value contained in `rows` is correct from using `util.inspect(rows)` on it inside that callback function. I just don't know how to bring it back up to the surface, so to speak. `dbHandler()` is called from other functions that pass the params and a result is expected in return.

Any insight would be tremendously helpful.

Using node.js with Express and mysql packages if that makes a difference.

```
function dbHandler(req, res, params) {
    pool_user.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            connection.release();
            res.json({
                "code"   : 100,
                "status" : "Error in connection database"
            });
            return;
        }
        connection.query(params.query_string, function (err, rows) {
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                res.json(rows);  // <<--- I want to get ahold of the value of `rows`
                //console.log(util.inspect(rows));
            }           
        });
        connection.on('error', function(err) {
            res.json({
                "code"   : 100,
                "status" : "Error in connection database"
            });
            return;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Asynchronous. You're accessing the global before the callback completes.

Comment: Where are you accessing `umadbro`? If you don't show us that part of the code where `umadbro` is unexpectedly `undefined`, we cannot help you with fixing it.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I was making incremental post edits. :P I'm not using `umadbro`. My question was confused (my fault) for something else.

Comment: OK whatever then to the current question: `res.json` seems to be quite good at "bringing the value back to the surface", isn't it? If those other functions that call `dbHandler`, then they should just supply their own callbacks that would then need to be called instead of `res.json`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

**Trying to return the result of an async function is an anti-pattern and will never work.**

## Instead, restructure the calling code.

### Not Like This - the anonymous callback does not return to the caller

```
new_data = api_request_data(auth, request, 
      function(error, data){ 
          return data;
});
store(new_data);
update_screen(new_data);
```

### Better

```
api_request_data(auth, request, 
       function(error, data){ 
          store(data);
          update_screen(data);
});
```

### Best

```
api_request_data(auth, request, 
       function(error, data){
          if (error){ 
                console.log(error);
                return;
          } 
          store(data);
          update_screen(data);
});
```

In your code, the data pipeline looks ok.

```
connection.query(params.query_string, function (err, rows) {
        connection.release();
        if(!err) {
            res.json(rows);  // <<--- I want to get ahold of the value of `rows`
            //console.log(util.inspect(rows));
        }           
    });
```

The code `res.json(rows);` in a node.js application will queue a JSON string containing the data in `rows` for writing to the current web connection referenced in `res`.

Your question suggests that the issue is that this line does not return data to the caller of `dbHandler()`, but no  trained node.js developer would expect that to happen. The code looks correct for delivering the data in `rows` to an over-the-web client of the node.js application.